# Users favorites and Memcached

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

Lets say I have two tables

```
posts
 - post_id
 - image

favorites
 - fav_id
 - post_id
 - user_id
```

When a user enters the site 10 posts are fetched from the db and displayed. What I am doing now is joining these tables together and looping through the results and there I can check if a user has favorited something or not.

Something like this:

```
SELECT p.*, f.fav_id
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN favorites f
ON p.post_id = f.post_id AND user_id = $user_id
LIMIT 10
```

This is fine except now I want to cache the results with **memcached** and the query cannot be different for each user because then the caching wouldn't work. I want all users to load posts from the same cache entry.

My first thought was that I could get all the users favorites when he logs in and save them to the cache and use it when he browses posts on the site. My friend suggested that this could get to heavy when users have many favorites and many users logged in at the same time.

I'm not sure how to approach this, what do you guys think?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The query itself is not specially intensive, so it should be fine regarding load on the server.

About what you mention, it doesn't seem to be clear; at least for me.

If you want to make a cache about favorites of a user, you need always a different query since you are using different data, specifically user_id. If what you want is to make, let's call it, many caches, one per user, that would be feasible, but, then you have the problem that you have to check if the user has something new in the favorite list, unless you update that specific cache when the user selects something new as favorite.

I would use a query to check for the favorites of each user at the beggining of the session and keep them in there until the end of the session, if the user adds something new, then I'll update that list in the session.

UPDATE
Considering your comment, I'll rebuild the cache when the user adds something to the list of favorites, less downtime for the user that way.

Also, you may use a simple query to obtain those results when the user logs in. A simple query will run quick and will provide results soon.

But once you have the favorites loaded in session, it should be no problem regarding performance, unless you have too many users, your store too much information on the session, or you have too much flow of data and queries all the time.

Comment: The actual query I'm using now is more complicated and it joins a few other tables. I just wanted to make things clean in this question but I should have mentioned it.

I was thinking I would delete the favorites cache entry with a unique key for that user so when he adds something to his favorites I would delete the cache and it would be rebuild the next time he loads the page and then the new entry would be included.